# 3D Rotation and camera angle?

Tags: xna

i am having alittle problem with my rotation. My model rotates but then goes slightly off the camera angle position not in the center. Here is my rotation code, is this correct?

```
matrix m = matrix.createrotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadian(30))
matrix object = matrix.createtranslation(objectPos) * m;
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the multiplication order? Depending on the `matrix` implementation the translation could be applied before the rotation, thus changing the rotation center.

Answer (score 1):

As Lucius notes in his comment, a matrix represents a sequence of linear transformations.  The order in which you multiply them together is important.

`RotationMatrix` * `TranslationMatrix` means, "Rotate this model around its axis in model space, then translate the rotated model into world space."

`TranslationMatrix` * `RotationMatrix` means, "Translate this model into world space, then rotate the model around the world's origin."

Change the order of your matrix multiplications.

As an aside, multiplying matrices using the `*` operator can quickly become expensive when you start adding more transformations to the sequence; it can end up creating a lot of extra matrices that are never actually used.  You can optimize this by using the static [`Multiply()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb198134.aspx) method on the `Matrix` class.